# Sending mail with msmtp failed -no such file or directory

Tags: debian-buster, msmtp

at the moment I try to send mails with msmtp from my Debian Buster vServer to my mail address. I've installed and configured msmtp like many tutorials. But when I test it I just get the error message

```
mail: /usr/bin/msmtp -t: No such file or directory
sendmail process failed with error code 1
```

I've checked the path. Msmtp is under /usr/bin/ folder. I configured and tried as root.
Has anyone an idea what the problem might be? Didn't find anything at Google. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What do you mean by "test it"? What exactly did you do that gave this error?

Comment: The steps I did:

Comment: 1. Apt install msmtp msmtp-mta mailutils

Comment: 2. Edited /etc/msmtprc with the smtp information like host, auth, security

Comment: 3. Edited /etc/mail.rc and added set sendmail='/usr/bin/msmtp -t'